# Publish a single iOS message to multiple AWS SNS Topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an iOS and Android application that allows the user to select multiple Topics (think 'my favorite sports teams') to subscribe to. I would like to send a single message to each of the Topic ARNs associated with the teams in the contest, using the PHP SDK.

Ideally, the user only receives a single message when they are subscribed to more than one of the Topics in the list.

I have not found a method described in the SNS documentation, other than publishing a message to a single Topic ARN - which would result in multiple messages received by the client (subscribed to those Topics).

Thank you in-advance.

Comment: I have the same problem as well. Are there any solutions for this? It's been 3 years :)

Answer (score 1):

From my research Amazon SNS still does not offer this feature. After looking through a few other providers of push notifications I found [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It offers versatile user targeting and you can achieve the desired "multi topic" behaviour by using user tags and segments. I'm not in any way associated with OneSignal - just posting my research results.